# Libparted error when opening GParted

Tags: partitioning, kernel, gparted

When I open Gparted, I get the next error "Partition(s) 1 on /dev/sdb have been written, but we have been unable to inform the kernel of the change, probably because it/they are in use.  As a result, the old partition(s) will remain in use.  You should reboot now before making further changes."

Comment: Does the problem persist after the suggested reboot?

Comment: Yes, the problem persisted but after run "Disks" from a live Ubuntu CD and deactivate and reactivate the partition, the problem has gone. Thank you for yor help.

Comment: If you solved your problem yourself, please [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) and accept it. Don’t put the answer in your question or the comments! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reboot many times the problem persisted but after run "Disks" from a live Ubuntu CD and deactivate and reactivate the partition, the problem has gone.